# Capacitor charge distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, capacitance

How does charge get redistributed between charged and uncharged capacitor, assuming they are connected?

Comment: Have you tried using Kirchoff's law to analyze the voltages and changes in current for the situation? Note, you'll want to stick a resistor in there, otherwise the charge redistributes itself evenly instantaneously ;)

Comment: In our syllabus, we have Kirchhoff voltage law only for resistors. However, can we apply for capacitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On connecting charged and uncharged capacitors(in parallel), charge flow between the two takes place (i.e. Charge flow from the one that is charged to the one that is uncgarged) till they achieve a **common potential**.

*Now, two cases may arise, one, when the same polarity plates are connected and the other when the opposite polarity plates are connected.*

For the first case:

Let the charges capacitor be $C_1$ and the uncharged capacitor be $C_2$.

Now supposing the charged capacitor was charged by applying a potential difference $V$, the charge stored in it will be $C_{1}V$.Charge on $C_2$ initially is zero. Now on connecting same polarity plates together, let the common potential be $V'$.

Now applying $Q=CV$,

$C_{1}V=(C_1+C_2).V'$

Now this equation can help you find common potential, and hence the final charges on capacitors etc.

Similarly you can solve the second case.

Hope your doubt got clarified. Feel free to ask if not.

Comment: Dont forget to upvote the answer or accept it if it helped you.